# How to start the Docker daemon offline at startup

Tags: docker

When I run my docker daemon without an internet connection, it fails with:

> Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localunixsocket - is it running?

Is there a way to make my docker daemon run offline ?

The only [reference](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-daemon-does-not-start-when-offline/32385)  I've found so far is on docker's forum (17/05/2017) and haven't received any answer.

Update: I can start the docker daemon offline with `sudo service docker start` but then the question becomes: how to start the docker daemon offline at startup? As it might be related to my distribution (Ubuntu), I've asked on "Ask Ubuntu": https://askubuntu.com/questions/937444/launch-docker-deamon-at-startup-when-offline (I don't think I've got enough rights to move the question itself - should I delete it?)